# Monitor certain object in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I know we have Watch to monitor a variable in Debug mode, you can the variable changing, removed, or being assigned to another object.

But what I mean is to monitor a centain object states in memory.

Say I have a method that will receive an object and assign into a variable

i.e:

```
void DoSomething(object anObject){
   object tempObject = anObject;
}
```

This method will be called more than 1 times.

If I use Watch on this tempObject, the tempObject in Watch will keep on changing when the new assigned object value.

What I interest here, is to only Watch this anObject instead.  Say on the 2nd Call to this method, I found out this anObject has centain parameter is incorrect, I want to trace this object, to see when will this incorrect parameter changed back to a correct parameter. (Even out of scope).

How can I do that?  Or is it possible to do it in Visual Studio?

Because right now I am having similar problem, I have a centain object I see it got disposed, but somehow somewhere is being used again and its said is not disposed.  Using Watch I have no idea if that's the same object I have been watching.

I hope I made this clear.

Comment: putting breakpoint in Dispose() will narrow down premature call. For other purposes you can always have conditional breakpoints.

Comment: @Ankush I already did, I seen the Dispose method got executed, a parameter changed.  But then later on I can see a object with same parameter but not disposed, I have no idea if that's the same object or not.  (In Disposed method is set a certain parameter to true).

Comment: You can evaluate ReferenceEqual and see if two objects are same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding a [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) to the object in question and watch it. From there you can see if the target of the `WeakReference` and the object in question are in fact the same object.

Comment: Visual Studio itself can't do these kind of stuff in debug mode for us? (I mean like as easy as we use Watch)  This is pretty much what I am doing right now, have to modifies the code to hold the object reference then check it myself...

Comment: Not that I know of. I can only assume this is easily solved by a clean design and proper placement of breakpoints.

Comment: And the reason I said to use WeakReference instead of what you are doing is that WeakReference will still allow an object to be collected by the GC. This way you can debug and not obstruct the normal flow of the application.

Answer (score 0):

An object will not get disposed by garbage collector as long as there is a strong reference to it. Some code may be calling Dispose on the object or you may be using Weak References.

Using Son of Strike debugging extension, you can trace the GC Roots for the object at any time. I am not sure if we can receive event notification though.